# Get bytes object from bytes object in string quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I wanted to use Whoosh in my application and followed the tutorial [here](http://pieceofpy.com/blog/2011/08/05/hooking-up-whoosh-and-sqlalchemy-(sawhoosh)/), which was written in 2011.

When I try to unpickle data in this block:

```
def results_to_instances(request, results):
    instances = []
    for r in results:
        cls = pickle.loads('{0}'.format(r.get('cls')))
        id = r.get('id')
        instance = request.db.query(cls).get(id)
        instances.append(instance)
    return instances
```

I get an error from the pickle.loads() command:

```
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

When I check what `'{0}'.format(r.get('cls'))` returns, it is type str, but the value is `"b'foo'"`.

How do I get the bytes object out of the string? Encoding it just returns `b"b'foo'"`.

The values are pickled in this block:

```
def first_index(self, writer):
        oid = u'{0}'.format(self.id)
        cls = u'{0}'.format(pickle.dumps(self.__class__))
        attributes = []
        for attr in self.__whoosh_value__.split(','):
            if getattr(self, attr) is not None:
                attributes.append(str(getattr(self, attr)))
        value = u' '.join(attributes)
        writer.add_document(id=oid, cls=cls, value=value)
```

So if there is a way to fix it at the root, that would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `r.get('cls')`. Wrapping it in `'{0}'.format()` makes a `bytes` into `str` in the first place, which is not what you want at all. Same goes for when you wrap `pickle.dumps` (immediately converting the useful `bytes` it returns to the useless formatted version). Basically all of your uses of `'{0}'.format()` make no sense, because they make `str` when you're trying to  work with the raw data.

Comment: Doesn't the `'{0}'` serve some purpose? An example of the full result is `b'\x80\x03cserver.models.models\ntext\nq\x00.'`

Comment: Quickly tried it out, I get the same error. Although `r.get('cls')` returns `b'foo'`, but it is still type str. What does that mean?

Comment: @Niel: It's because you also had the same error when you pickled it. You wrapped in a `format` that converted the `bytes` to `str`. All `'{0}'.format(x)` does is stringify `x` (it's equivalent to `str(x)` in the vast majority of cases), but pickles are a binary data format, and have no business being converted to `str`.

Comment: That makes sense. I got the code from a working tutorial so I was hesitant to change it too much. Should I then also encode whatever I'm pickling?

Comment: Basically, stop doing [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming); you're trotting out bits of code quasi-religiously, without understanding what it actually does; [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) isn't make "make it work" powder, it exists for a purpose, and you need to understand it rather than blindly wrapping things in it.

Comment: Lol what? If I understood it I wouldn't be asking these questions.

Comment: @Niel: Huh? pickling takes arbitrary objects and converts them to `bytes`; if you pass the same `bytes` back into `loads`, you get back the object. It's a serialization format, but calling it "encoding" (which in the context of Python primarily refers to converting between text `str` and binary `bytes`) is missing the point.